# Delphi Android. How to make a combo box with fulltext search autocomplete support?

Tags: android, delphi, combobox

Can you give me enlightenment how can I search for an item in a combobox by typing a few characters and then appearing several options in the item combobox containing that character? My Combobox contains thousands of files. I got the tutorial only on VCL, but I haven't found the idea on FMX Android.Thanks

Comment: How do you type anything in a `FMX` `TComboBox` ?

Comment: I am not saying that typing in a combobox, but rather a method of finding items in a combobox by typing characters, may be represented by the tedit component

Comment: Ok, then start by looking at `TComboEdit` and using its `OnTyping()` or `OnKeyDown()` events. Come back with your attempts to solve it, if you hit obstacles.

Comment: You could use something like this: http://yaroslavbrovin.ru/new-approach-of-development-of-firemonkey-control-control-model-presentation-part-2-tedit-with-autocomplete-en/